# How to implement INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE aka upsert in CakePHP 3?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, insert-update, upsert, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP 3 and MySQL.

I would like to implement a `INSERT on DUPLICATE KEY  UPDATE` aka `upsert` query via `CakePHP 3` model.

**Given the following table:**

```
+----+----------+-----+
| id | username | age |
+----+----------+-----+
|  1 | admin    |  33 |
|  2 | Timmy    |  17 |
|  3 | Sally    |  23 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

where `id` is Primary Key and `username` is unique index

When I have the following values awaiting to be upserted:

```
Felicia, 27
Timmy, 71
```

I expect the following result **after** the upsert:

```
+----+----------+-----+
| id | username | age |
+----+----------+-----+
|  1 | admin    |  33 |
|  2 | Timmy    |  71 |
|  3 | Sally    |  23 |
|  4 | Felicia  |  27 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

**I know how to do upsert in MySQL query:**

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `age`) 
VALUES ('Felicia', 27), ('Timmy', 71) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`username`=VALUES(`username`),`age`=VALUES(`age`);
```

**I know how to do this in more than a single query in CakePHP3.**

```
   $newUsers = [
        [
            'username' => 'Felicia',
            'age' => 27,
        ],
        [
            'username' => 'Timmy',
            'age' => 71,
        ],
    ];

    foreach ($newUsers as $newUser) {
        $existingRecord = $this->Users->find()
            ->select(['id'])
            ->where(['username' => $newUser['username']])
            ->first();

        if (empty($existingRecord)) {
            $insertQuery = $this->Users->query();
            $insertQuery->insert(array_keys($newUser))
                ->values($newUser)
                ->execute();
        } else {
            $updateQuery = $this->Users->query();
            $updateQuery->update()
                ->set($newUser)
                ->where(['id' => $existingRecord->id])
                ->execute();
        }
    }
```

What I want to know is :

**is there a way to do upsert using CakePHP 3 in a single line even if I use chaining?**

Please advise how do I implement that.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. Please post what have you tried to date and what problem do you have.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0: How to do an insert on duplicate key update?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852904/cakephp-3-0-how-to-do-an-insert-on-duplicate-key-update)

Comment: just to clear: it´s no duplicate of [CakePHP 3.0: How to do an insert on duplicate key update?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852904/cakephp-3-0-how-to-do-an-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: @Dirk You aren't clarifying anything, you're just making a statement. Care to explain why you think it's not a duplicate?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk is that better now?

Comment: @Dirk Thank you for writing that question. I used lorenzo answer to answer my own question.

Comment: @ndm I agree this is a duplicate, but I feel I offer more info in my question to be considered as the "authoritative question" on this topic after my edit. What say you?

Comment: @KimStacks I'm ndm and I would approve that message :) It's definitely the better question now, it would have been nice if it would have looked like this from the very beginning.

Comment: @ndm no problems. I need the occasional kick up the bum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the answer provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/24990944/80353, I want to rephrase this using the code sample given in the question.

To run upsert on the following records

```
Felicia, 27
Timmy, 71
```

into this table

```
+----+----------+-----+
| id | username | age |
+----+----------+-----+
|  1 | admin    |  33 |
|  2 | Timmy    |  17 |
|  3 | Sally    |  23 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

the best way is to write it as

```
$newUsers = [
    [
        'username' => 'Felicia',
        'age' => 27,
    ],
    [
        'username' => 'Timmy',
        'age' => 71,
    ],
];

$columns = array_keys($newUsers[0]);

$upsertQuery = $this->Users->query();

$upsertQuery->insert($columns);

// need to run clause('values') AFTER insert()
$upsertQuery->clause('values')->values($newUsers);

$upsertQuery->epilog('ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `username`=VALUES(`username`), `age`=VALUES(`age`)')
                ->execute();
```

Check [this](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Database.Query.html#_epilog) out for details about `epilog`

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26592779/80353) out for details on how to write insert multiple records in single query